# Styling a Campaign Monitor Subscribe Button

Tags: javascript, css

Following is the code of a [Campaign Monitor subscribe button](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/new-features/2013/02/say-hello-to-the-subscribe-button/). I need to increase the width, height and especially the size of the text of the button. I've been digging for hours but can't find any solution. Can anyone help me through this please?

```css
<div style="width:115px; height:28px; -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); -moz-transform: rotate(270deg); -ms-transform: rotate(270deg); -o-transform: rotate(270deg); transform: rotate(270deg); left: -43px; top: 370px; position: fixed;">
<div class="createsend-button" style="width: 152px; height:28px;" data-listid="t/45/C0E/291/0259AABA5E6A8C63">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function () { var e = document.createElement('script'); e.type = 'text/javascript'; e.async = true; e.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') + '://btn.createsend1.com/js/sb.min.js?v=3'; e.className = 'createsend-script'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(e, s); })();
</script>

</div>
```

Comment: you want to dynamically change those properties?

Comment: I would suggest contacting the support staff at Campaign Monitor for assistance with your issue (given that is a CM script).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have control over your html, it's best practice not to use inline styles like you've got. CSS honors styles in a certain order ([read more here](http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css)). Having your styles directly within the html tags takes precedence over styles you add anywhere else. What's more, is you have an `!important` on your text size, which is specifically used for overriding.

Move these styles to an external stylesheet if you can. If you don't have control, you'll need to change them with javascript.

Comment: Well, i don't have access to the external sheet, don't have anything except this code. I have read through some similar posts like me and people suggest using javascript to control the iframe that is called by the above code. But I am not sure how to use that.

Comment: How are you able to edit the code? Can you explain the context of this a little more? If you can edit the code you posted, then you can just change the css values inside the `style="..."` tag, and the button will change.